# sqlite3.OperationalError:near syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

my code is the following:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

def execute_sql(sql_command, sql_cursor):
    result = sql_cursor.execute(sql_command)
    return result


def print_0th_col(sql_result):
    for next_record in sql_result:
        print(next_record[0])

def create_tables(sql_cursor):
    sql_command = '''CREATE TABLE artist
    (artist_id INTEGER UNIQUE
    artist_name VARCHAR(100),
    age INTEGER,
    members INTEGER,
    formation VARCHAR(4))
    '''
    execute_sql(sql_command,sql_cursor)
    sql_command = '''CREATE TABLE songs
    (song_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
    song_name VARCHAR(100),
    Band_id INTEGER UNIQUE)
    '''
    execute_sql(sql_command, sql_cursor) 

    conn = sql.connect('ex9.db')

    sql_cursor = conn.cursor() 

    conn.commit() 
    conn.close()



 def drop_table(sql_cursor,table_name):
  sql_command = '''DROP TABLE ''' + table_name
  execute_sql(sql_command, sql_cursor)
```

and when i debug it, it says sqlite3.OperationalError:near "artist_name":syntax error.

---

can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `artist_id` line should be:

```
(artist_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
```

Your code is missing the comma `,` at the end.

Comment: Thx!, but when i run the code again, it shows: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:artist

Comment: @user3879034 I'm glad I could help. If my answer solves your question, please feel free to click the check mark to the left of the answer to select it as correct. Please see [What does it mean when an answer is accepted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more information.

Comment: @user3879034 as far as your second comment, I'm not sure what's going on. I ran the [these commands](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/7a55b0312db8ecd9c0ce) and everything worked fine. I'd inspect the DB to see if there's anything left over from running the code the first time, and drop any tables that are there before starting over fresh.

Comment: Thank you for your help. after i added the drop table function,drop_table(sql_cursor,'artist') it gives me operationalError: no such table:artist

Comment: @user3879034 that's correct, you need to create a table before you can drop it. To list the tables in a DB, run `for table in cursor.execute("""SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"""): print(table)`